# How to write a non-blocking for loop in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nonblocking

I have two collections in mongoose db. I have to find all the documents in a collection. After that, i have to iterate all the documents to find the corresponding document in second collection. For that, i was thinking to use `for` loop. But,  since it is `blocking` in nature. How can I perform my task.

```
const docs = await collection1.find({name:"asdf"})
for(let i=0;i<docs.length;i++){
    const doc2 = await collection2.findOne({address:docs.address})
}
```

Comment: It's not blocking at all! While the db is retrieving results inside the loop (`await collection2.findOne(...)`), the main thread is taking care of "other things". Async/await does not block the event loop, in simple words `await` is just sugar-coating the nesting of promises and callbacks so that your code structure looks "flat". Something like reading a file with `fs.readFileSync()` inside the loop (or anywhere in your code) would block the event loop, but that's not the case with `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand your problem, but if I do, I think you can push all yours promises inside an array, instead of using await. After that you can use the function `Promise.all` to await in on place for all promises inside the array. You can find below an example with your code:

```
const docs = await collection1.find({name:"asdf"})
const docs2 = [];
for(let i=0;i<docs.length;i++){
    docs2.push(collection2.findOne({address:docs.address}));
}

Promise.all(docs2).then((values) => {
  // at this point all your documents are ready
  // and your for is not blocking
  console.log(values);
});
```

But you have to be carefull to not abuse of this, if you fill an array with a lot of promises, it can lead to performance/memory issues.
Regards

Comment: sorry, but i meant to ask is if I will use a for loop, then it will block the event loop. How can i avoid either using for loop or use it such that it does not block event loop

Comment: @anitashrivastava the for loop itself is "blocking", but it's fast. Just don't do anything blocking IN the loop (like shown in this answer) and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I am new with node js, how can i push the found result to the corresponding doc array object's index ?

Comment: on my example, values, just after the 'then' it's an array. It contains all your docs

Comment: Now, before using this code, think about the fact that you'll be flooding your database with parallel queries (it could be thousands!) and that this code should probably run with a `collection2.find()` that returns all docs you need instead of individual `findOne()` calls which are much slower. Basically running `findOne()` inside any kind of loop, with or without promises, is a database client antipattern and a performance code smell.

Comment: But, I cannot find all the documents at once because i have to find for each document found in collection 1.

Comment: @anitashrivastava: it depends on how many elements are there in `docs`, but a query with `$in` operator is a good way to rewrite this code.